# What's the difference between response, respond, reply and answer?

Tags: difference

What are the differences between the words "response", "respond", "reply" and "answer"? Which can be used as both nouns and verbs, and which cannot?

Comment: "which can be used as a verb and noun"? What have you found by checking dictionaries yourself? And what *specifically* are you having trouble understanding about what you found?

Answer (score 1):

Response is a noun, respond is a verb, reply is both a verb and a noun, and answer is both a verb and a noun.

Replies are usually verbal or in writing, but responses can be more: a response can also be a facial or other bodily gesture or action.

Answer carries with it its association to questions, but can also generally  be used in similar scenarios as respond/response and reply.